# Event Hub Error: Exception: Put token failed. status-code: 401 Unauthorized TrackingId

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-eventhub

I am working on an MVC Web Application which sends data as a producer to an Event Hub.
I have successfully set up event hub name space and event hub and was able to successfully send data while running a project in my local machine via local-host.

However when i deployed an application to Azure's Cloud i am getting the following error exception
while trying to send data:

**Put token failed. status-code: 401, status-description: Unauthorized TrackingId:XXXX-XXXXX**

Both Event Hub and Web Application is under the same subscription.
SAS Policy Connection string is from the root of a name-space.

Works fine locally, but receiving error on the Azure's Cloud when accessing that page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things you may need to check:

- Make sure VNET and IP rules are properly configured.
- Make sure both local and cloud deployments use the same connection string.

Comment: Missing VNET is probably what is currently causing an issue, i initially included my local IP address within the networking - file wall, this would explain why i have no issues sending data locally.

Comment: in Event Hub, added VNET settings and added private end point for the same subscription. still getting the same error. I wonder if there is anything i need to add on Web Site Application besides turning the manage Identity on and adding azure role "Azure Event Hubs Data Owner" to it ... ?

Comment: @VitoldUSA you said the client uses a SAS connection string, so, managed Identity has no use in your case. Try removing all VNET and IP rules temporarily from EH namespace and see if it helps. If VNET turns to be the issue then either add your website to the same VNET or whitelist client IPs.

Comment: This issue is resolved. Thanks that is what i did, added client IPs and it started to work. Thanks for the feedback everyone.